# A proper way to call the "scalar/vector" property of a quantity

Tags: linear-algebra

If a quantity can be either a scalar or a vector, how would one call that property? I could think of scalarity but I don't think such a term exists.

Comment: Would you like to give an example of such a quantity ?

Comment: @TomCollinge An abstract quantity that can be instantiated with something concrete, e.g. either speed or velocity.

Comment: If you're looking for a word to use in sentences like, I don't know, "the *frabjosity* of speed is *scalaresque*, but the frabjosity of velocity is *vectorial*", then I don't think such a word exists. The best I can think of is just *type*, like in computer science: speed is a value of scalar type.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, that's what I'm looking for - that "frabjosity" word. Type would be fine until you want to concretize how the value is stored in the computer memory: it is a single precision floating point number or it is a double precision floating point number. That they call type (data type) in CS.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your speed/velocity example. Speed is usually defined as a scalar, e.g. 60 km/hr. Velocity is usually associated with a direction as well, e.g. flying at 900 km/hr in a northly direction.

If a quantity is a vector (e.g. velocity) you can refer to the *magnitude* of the vector (speed in this example) as a way to refer to the direction-less scalar associated with it. Conversely, if a scalar quantity represents the magnitude of a vector (as speed does of velocity) then you can refer to the *direction* associated with the scalar to give the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if such case can possibly exist, usually a scalar is being seen as a special vector with 1 dimension, you should be encouraged to think about a scalar as a 0D vector because this is likely to simplify your mindset about linear algebra.

Tipically, aka from my experience, the word that will identify what you are looking for is [module](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Module.html).

both the *rank* and *magnitude* word are misleading, especially in linear algebra, with *rank* being a much more appropriate and popular concept with matrices and *magnitude* being a really generic word that refers to how big an object is in really vague terms, sometimes this word doesn't even refers to an object but it also can be used in conjunction with rough estimations, for example you can say *"a 9 figure number has a bigger magnitude that a 4 figure one"* or *"this problem is about a different level of magnitude if compared to the other one"* without mentioning a really "exact" quantity.

Comment: @TomCollinge 0D, my bad, it's a typo.